# Is code trolling on homework questions OK?

Tags: discussion

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109337/java-program-for-build-report

That is a homework question. It has been closed. Am I allowed to troll the asker with innocent code snippets? Ya know just things that will troll them harmlessly?

[Code-troll rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/746/code-troll-rules?rq=1)

^^

I have realized my mistakes and realize how dumb I was being.

Comment: How many downvotes can I get? (not annoyed just expected this) Kinda funny

Comment: Note that [code trolling is considered off-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1517/20260) even when the asker is not actually looking for homework help.

Comment: I don't think editing "I'm removing this" into the body of this question helps at all. You should leave the original question so that the answers make sense in context. If you want to say that you've changed your mind, that could be an additional section, or if you really want this removed, you could [flag] it for a moderator to remove.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## [Be Nice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

That's Stack Exchange's prime directive. Trolling someone, for whatever reasons you may think you have, is *not* OK. My favorite part of the *Be Nice* page says the following.

> Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.*

So, if someone comes here with their homework, it is of course acceptable to notify them that we won't do their homework for them, but that's also where the interaction should stop. Trolling, belittling, name calling, bullying, and any other kind of confrontation that is intended for your amusement is not only completely disrespectful and unnecessary, it is so far over the line that it doesn't even make sense to have a meta discussion about it.

TL;DR Trolling other users, even if they're here for the wrong reasons and *especially* if they're new, is not only not allowed, **it will get you suspended**.

Answer (score 21):

## No.

(Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 3.)

<sub>(Honestly, I don't even see why this is something that needs to be discussed. This isn't reddit. Regardless of how misguided some user's attempt at using the site may be, trolling them can only be detrimental to PPCG's reputation.)</sub>